# Does max size that can be allocated with kmalloc() depends on size of free_area[]?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Does max size that can be allocated with `kmalloc()` depends on size of `free_area[]`?

Answer (score 0):

It cannot exceed the max order of free_area, because the slab rely on the buddy allocator.